# Out of memory exception in for loop C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exception

I am reading a binary file. If I read one file, my code works fine. But when I read files in a folder, i get error, which is pasted below. I will add some code I am using to read files. I am reading files in byte array:

```
byte[] b = File.ReadAllBytes(args);
```

and storing data in array (indicative code):

```
len=400000000;
public ArrayList rawData1 = new ArrayList();
UInt32[] fff = Enumerable.Repeat((UInt32)4095, len/4).ToArray();    


public ReadRawFiles{
            while (true){
            rawData1.Add((double)(BitConverter.ToUInt32(b, curPos) & fff[i]));
            i++;
            }
}
b=null; //clear array
```

It works if I read only one file, though slow (size is about 40 MB). But when I add path of a folder and read again, I get the error.

```
List<ReadRawFiles> list = new List<ReadRawFiles>();
ReadRawFiles rawFiles;
foreach (var f in sFiles)
                    {
                      rawFiles = new ReadRawFiles(f.File,true,true);
                      list.Add(rawFiles);

                       //rawFiles=null; //clear??
                    }
```

I am not very clear how garbage collector works. Please let me know if I missed something.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit:
codes:
http://www.codesend.com/view/4aadd067dfd26ea88396afbd3cd3fc22/
http://www.codesend.com/view/f8f798224e54c28a00865ca9aff514e5/

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
  Message=Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Buffer`1.ToArray()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at program.ReadRawFiles..ctor(String args, Nullable`1 flagraw, Nullable`1 dualChannel) in E:\projects\development\vs_test\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\param.cs:line 83
       at SePSI.MainWindow.Add_folder(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in E:\projects\development\vs_test\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 196
       at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
       at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(Object arg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at SePSI.App.Main() in E:\projects\development\vs_test\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Do post the actual code. Also, as the name of the exception suggests, you're running out of memory. Pretty normal if you store a bunch of large files in memory.

Comment: How many files are in that folder and how much memory do they take combined?

Comment: true = (b.Length- curPos)>=4 ; and curPos=curPos+4 ; for UInt32

Comment: What is it that you actually want to **do** here? because loading those files into memory is simply a really really bad idea, and I have ***no clue*** what you want that huge `fff` array for. The trick when working with large binary is to *stream* the data. So: what are you actually trying to *do* here? The use of `ArrayList` doesn't make your intentions any clearer (`List<T>` for some `T` would be much clearer)

Comment: You are putting every single file you are reading into a collection.  If you are getting this exception you are trying to use more memory then your system supports.  How many files are you trying to read exactly?

Comment: i disabled List, that means I am not reading all files at once, I am reading one by one. So I read next files, I should loose previous file.

Comment: Your code is a non-compiling mess, making all answers guesswork. Clean up and try again.

Comment: You could probably fix the worst problems here simply by removing `fff` from the code. That array ***serves no purpose***. Just `&` with `(uint)4095` directly. No need to fill an array of it.

Comment: disabled fff. after reading 4 files, i get same exception,

Comment: with `b=null` and `rawFiles=null` you are just clearing the *reference* to the object, reclaiming the memory is up to the CG. In the case of `rawFiles` there is still a reference in that `list` so that memory can *not* be reclaimed as it's still in use.

Comment: @HansKesting it worked for one individual file, but when i read in a folder with 4 files, i dont even read once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some very inefficient parts here; loading entire files into memory for one, and the unclear `fff` array for another. The `ArrayList` that holds `double` for a third (that involves boxing each `double` - very bad here).

I strongly suggest trying to simplify and *stream* the data, for example:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
List<double> rawData = new List<double>();
foreach(var path in paths)
{
    using(var file = File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        while(TryRead(file, buffer, 4))
        {
            const uint MASK = 4095;
            var val = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0) & MASK;
            // note that this line looks really dodgy
            rawData.Add((double)val);
        }
    }
}
```

using the utility method to fill an entire chunk of 4 bytes (or fail):

```
static bool TryRead(Stream s, byte[] buffer, int bytes)
{
    int read = s.Read(buffer, 0, bytes), offset;
    if (read <= 0) return false; // no more data

    bytes -= read;
    offset = read;
    while (bytes > 0 && (read = s.Read(buffer, offset, bytes)) > 0)
    {
        bytes -= read;
        offset += read;
    }
    if (bytes != 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
    return true; // success
}
```

I must emphasize, though:

- the `uint`-to-`double` conversion looks very unlikely; that is *not* how you would read a double as binary
- storing all the data as `double` sounds equally unlikely - I can't think of any obvious scenarios where that would be useful

Comment: I am reproducing a matlab code, this is how it was implemented there. I will try what you said . Thanks a lot.

Comment: and my file is 40 MB, isnt it fast to read it all in memory, and clean once you are done with it?

Comment: @Naresh 40 MB is still pretty sizeable. Do you know what is faster than allocating 40 MB? *not* allocating 40 MB! Especially if you are in a 32-bit process and are destroying your large-object-heap. Likewise, the 98MB `fff` array that is ***completely unexplained*** will be doing a lot of harm. The vast quantity of boxing (`ArrayList`) is another huge problem. Since the code in the question is very unclear, I can only offer pointers...

Comment: I am a matlab user, so I am implementing similar things, i am not clear on memory usage, since matlab handles most of the stuff. I will look into more details. Its a great help. Thanks

Comment: if i disable the List that stores references, I can read complete folder.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume it would be due to this:

```
while (true)
{
    rawData1.Add((double)(BitConverter.ToUInt32(b, curPos) & fff[i]));
    i++;
}
```

You have no termination condition, it will continue forever and continues to eat resources by incrementing `i` and adding data into the `rawData` ArrayList.

Comment: The OP's code doesn't make sense (see "indicative code"), and as it works for one file, let's assume there isn't an infinite loop in the *actual* code.

Comment: @ken2k - I don't see how the condition is terminated.  What appears to work for 1 file may actually not be, i.e. the OP sees the desired output but the program is still consuming unneeded memory - however the exception has not been thrown.

Comment: i is set to 0 per file, and i read 2 files before i get exception.

Comment: @DarrenDavies There isn't exit conditions, because it isn't real code. `ReadRawFiles` doesn't have parameters. Code doesn't even compile.

Comment: i get exception at:
UInt32[] fff = Enumerable.Repeat((UInt32)4095, len/4).ToArray();

Comment: code works for one by one file, so readraFiles is ok. it works. But in loop i run out, and i pasted the while loop.

Comment: @Naresh "indicative" code that isn't actually *indicative* is simply "unhelpful"... now; what are you actually trying to *do* here? because the code makes it unclear.

Comment: i understand, i will paste code full code to see the problem.

Comment: @Naresh - Just update your question with those functions they can't be that long.